# How can I access an an arraylist from a different class in Java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;

public class Cards
{
    public static enum cards
    {
        D_A, D_2, D_3, D_4, D_5, D_6, D_7, D_8, D_9, D_10, D_J, D_Q, D_K,
        H_A, H_2, H_3, H_4, H_5, H_6, H_7, H_8, H_9, H_10, H_J, H_Q, H_K,
        C_A, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5, C_6, C_7, C_8, C_9, C_10, C_J, C_Q, C_K,
        S_A, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5, S_6, S_7, S_8, S_9, S_10, S_J, S_Q, S_K,
    }

    public Cards()
    {
        ArrayList<cards> deck; 
        deck = new ArrayList<cards>(51);
        for (cards card : cards.values())
        {
            deck.add(card);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        String img = deck.get(2).toString()+".gif";     
        System.out.println(img);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cards CardDeck = new Cards();
    }
}
```

I want to access the arraylist in a different class. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the ArrayList you need to have the list as a member of the class.
Then you need to either establish an accessor method, or make that member variable public (not recommended).

The first solution is provided here:

```
public class Cards
{
    private ArrayList<cards> deck; 

    public static enum cards
    {
        D_A, D_2, D_3, D_4, D_5, D_6, D_7, D_8, D_9, D_10, D_J, D_Q, D_K,
        H_A, H_2, H_3, H_4, H_5, H_6, H_7, H_8, H_9, H_10, H_J, H_Q, H_K,
        C_A, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5, C_6, C_7, C_8, C_9, C_10, C_J, C_Q, C_K,
        S_A, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5, S_6, S_7, S_8, S_9, S_10, S_J, S_Q, S_K,
    }

    public Cards()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<cards>(51);
        for (cards card : cards.values())
        {
            deck.add(card);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        String img = deck.get(2).toString()+".gif";     
        System.out.println(img);
    }
    public ArrayList <cards> getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cards CardDeck = new Cards();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Cards.cards.D_A` or whichever you want. Don't forget to import the class if they are not in the same package...

Comment: +1 first with best. I'm getting the Human verification *every time* I answer today, it just ain't fair.

Comment: So if i just wanted the whole list youd put Cards.cards ?

Comment: This how you would declare a variable of this enum type - Cards.cards myCard = Cards.cards.D_A. see more here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Comment: @Sam yes you can get it but you need to call Cards.cards.values(). This shows how to iterate over all values of your enumeration printing the names of its elements. `int counter = 0;
  for(Cards.cards c : Cards.cards.values())
  {
   System.out.println("counter"+counter+"; c.name()=" + c.name());
   counter++;
  }`   Just add it as the final line of the main. BTW the link by @MByD shows a different solution to your problem which you might consider useful.

Comment: +1 @MByD the link is great especially as it might be a nicer solution to @Sam 's problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's static, Cards.cards ought to work.

Comment: I got it for over 10 times a few hours ago... so I know how you feel +1 :)